# Yii url rules for main page

Tags: yii, yii-validation

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'class'=>'application.components.UrlManager',
            'urlSuffix'=>'/',
            'baseUrl'=>'',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<language:\w{2}>'   => 'page/index',
                ''   => 'page/index',
                '<language:\w{2}>/page/<alias:.*>' => 'pages/read',
            )
```

link "/en/page/index" works fine
links "/" and "/en" returns the error "Unable to resolve the request" page / index ".

what is wrong with the rules

```
'<language:\w{2}>' => 'page/index'
'' => 'page/index',
```

?

**UPD:**

pagesController has an action:

```
public function actionRead($alias){

            //some php code...

            if($model==null)
            {
                throw new CHttpException(404,'page not found...');
            }else
            {
                $this->render('read',array('model'=>(object)$model));
            }

}
```

Comment: Is your controller called PageController or PagesController? Your last rule (the one that works) says pages but the others say page.

Comment: My controller name is PagesController, but I'm create the rule '<language:\w{2}>/page/<alias:.*>' => 'pages/read' for "page"

Comment: If you change the first two rules to be 'pages/index' instead of 'page/index' do you get the same error? If you do, you may need to post your controller code because the rules look like they should work apart from that.

Comment: 'pages/index' and 'page/index' returns an error: "Unable to resolve the request" page(s)/index "

Comment: Is actionRead the only action that your PagesController has? actionIndex is the action I'm interested in because that's the one your broken URL rules are calling. Unless you have declared actionRead as the default action?

Comment: page/index == pages/read/index

Comment: Sorry but that isn't clear to me when looking at your code snippets above. I feel like there are important parts missing that are preventing me from understanding what's wrong. I recommend that you either post more detail or wait to see if someone else answers, because I can't help you based on the above and these comments are an "extended discussion" now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules that don't work are redirecting to `page/index`, meaning that they're going to try and access `PageController.php`, and within that controller, they're going to try an access `actionIndex`.  It doesn't sound like you have either a controller `PageController.php`, much less an `actionIndex` within that controller.

You need to fix the targets of those rules to include valid controller/action combinations.